Is it possible for a user of CloudCannon to change easily global colors of my site?
I'm beginner in Eleventy, CloudCannon and not very good in english. Sorry for my mistakes.
I have an eleventy static site
with global css values in my css file in :root
I installed the site in CloudCannon.
With CloudCannon, in my site, a user can change easily some items from json data files, some variables presents in front matter or some editable text.
But I would like the global css variables been accessibles for the user for that he can easily change colors of the site only from one place, and not for each page. For exemple, he wants to change the
--secondary-color created in :root.
Is it possible ? What can I do ?
For exemple, I would like to have the global css variables in a Json file. But I don't know how to do it.
